# AngularJS $q.all() results are null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

I'm trying to implement a $q.all to run some functions and then return all the outputs into a function attached to the .then at the end.

At the moment the promises look like they're calling in the correct order and the $all .then is occurring at the end, but the results variable comes back with an array of nulls (one for each promise in the $q.all)

JS Fiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/QqKuk/120/ and I'm using angular 1.0.1

The below is a simplified example of the code I have.

Here is my html, simply just there to display some debug text and the output.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>{{fromThen}}</p>
    <p>{{fromThen2}}</p>
    <p>{{runOrder}}</p>
</div>
```

and here is my controller, in reality logOne, logTwo, and logThree aren't going to be identical functions.

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {

```
var logOne = function (value) {
    $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value;
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    deffered.promise.then( function() {
            $scope.runOrder = $scope.runOrder + '.logOne()';
            $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value.toUpperCase();
            deffered.resolve(value);
            return deffered.promise;
    });

    deffered.resolve();
};

var logTwo = function (value) {
    $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value;
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    deffered.promise.then( function() {
            $scope.runOrder = $scope.runOrder + '.logTwo()';
            $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value.toUpperCase();
            deffered.resolve(value);
            return deffered.promise;
    });

    deffered.resolve();
};

var logThree = function (value) {
    $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value;
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    deffered.promise.then( function() {
            $scope.runOrder = $scope.runOrder + '.logThree()';
            $scope.fromThen = $scope.fromThen + value.toUpperCase();
            deffered.resolve(value);
            return deffered.promise;
    });

    deffered.resolve();
};


$scope.fromThen = '';
$scope.fromThen2 = 'No Value';
$scope.runOrder = '';


$q.all([logOne('One'), logTwo('Two'), logThree('Three')])
                    .then(function(results) {
                        $scope.runOrder = $scope.runOrder + '.then';
                        $scope.fromThen2 = results;
                    });

}
```

The output I'm getting is

OneTwoThreeONETWOTHREE
[null,null,null]
.logOne().logTwo().logThree().then

Which to me looks like things are calling in the correct order, so I'm confused why I'm getting nulls in the return value. Am I using the defer.resolve(value) incorrectly?

I've looked at some of the other examples on here but I haven't been able to work out why I'm not getting a result.

Thanks for any help you can give. Since this is also my first post, any tips on what information i should also include (or didn't need to include) would also be appreciated.

Thanks.
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not returning your promises from the log functions themselves for `$q.all` to follow.  You're resolving the promises and returning them somewhere, but not to anywhere that's listening.  Functions inside calls to `.then` are called by `$q` and the return values are sent to the resolution callbacks for the promises `.then` itself returns.  Your promising functions should take the form:

```
var function = doSomthingDeferred(data) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  doSomethingDeferredWith(data).then(function(deferredResult) {
    var processedResult = processDeferredResult(deferredResult);
    deferred.resolve(processedResult);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

*Alternatively*

```
var function = doSomthingDeferred(data) {
  return doSomethingDeferredWith(data).then(function(deferredResult) {
    var processedResult = processDeferredResult(deferredResult);
    return processedResult;
  });
}
```

In your case, when you `doSomethingDeferredWith(data)` you:

```
function doSomethingDeferredWith(data) {
  var deferredMore = $q.defer();
  $scope.fromThen += data;
  deferredMore.resolve($scope.fromThen);
```

This particular action doesn't really *need* to be deferred, it finishes immediately, but if you were querying an `$http` based service, then you'd get your `deferredMore` promise back:

```
  return deferredMore.promise;
}
```

Then, after you're done doing that, you're going to get some result as a parameter to a function referenced in a call to `.then` on a `promise` like the one returned from `doSomethingDeferredWith`:

```
doSomethingDeferredWith(data).then(function(deferredResult) {
```

Now, because of the way `$q` works, the call to `doSomethingDeferredWith(data)` returns a promise, `.then` is called on that promise and the function passed in is queued up, **but is not executed until the current script loop ends**.  This means that `.then` is called, the function is queued, and then `doSomethingDeferred` continues executing, returns, and its calling function then continues executing until the call stack has cleared.  Only after that does `$q` have the opportunity to come back and run all of the callbacks for resolved promises.

In your code, `doSomethingDeferred`, the various `log***` functions, do not actually return a promise.  They return `undefined`.  If you instead return the promise we created and will resolve when `$q` runs the callback instead of at the end of `doSomethingDeferred`, you'll get your data in the callback for `$q.all`.

To fix your code, change the `deffered.resolve();` calls at the end of each of your log files to `return deffered.promise;`  Then, the return values for the log functions won't be `undefined`, they'll be promises that `$q` can follow and run a callback on all three of their `.resolve` calls at once after all three calls are made, setting your `$scope.runFrom2` value to an array of `['One','Two','Three']` as each individual promise resolves with the `value` from the closure frame of the deferring function.

> **tl;dr Version**
>
> Change the `deffered.resolve();` calls at the end of each of your log files to `return deffered.promise;`

Comment: That was exactly what I need, thanks for the tip about using an extra defer in doSomethingDeferredWith() as this was something else I'd be moving on to.

Comment: Yeah, often you'll use the deferred/promise pattern with services that are deferred themselves, like `$http`.  What `$http` is essentially doing is creating a new deferred object and resolving it in the `onreadystatechange` handler for the underlying `XmlHttpRequest`.  It's also important to remember that `.then` returns a promise itself which is resolved when the function passed in as a parameter returns, allowing you to chain promises, even into a `$q.all` call.